# Working with Github clones and local repos: Cloud9 IDE

Tags: git, github, cloud9-ide

I recently tried using the [Cloud9 online IDE](http://c9.io/). It starts by creating a clone of your Github repo. My regular local use of git is fairly simple (init, status, commit, push to Github, branch, edit, pull, merge...), but because I don't usually clone, I haven't got my autopilot head around how to:

- push changes made in my C9 *clone* back to the *original repo in Github*.

[this outline guide suggests using the *same username* for github and C9](https://gist.github.com/885133), but a no-clutter step-by-step is what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you **auth** with your **Github account** in cloud9 and clone a Github project, then if you git push it will push to the original repo in Github

*[JJ]* If you cloned the project in Cloud9 before (via the command line, so not via the UI on the dashboard), you can do `git remote add upstream git@github.com:your/repo.git`. Now you have another remote that you can either pull from (`git pull upstream master` or push to `git push upstream master`).

Answer (score 1):

Commit as usual using the C9 CLI, then simply run `git push` from the C9 CLI, as you would normally when developing on your machine.

Comment: problem: when I did this, `git push` from the C9 CLI pushed to the C9 clone, not my repo on Github.

Comment: @DaveEveritt: Apologies, It was seamless for me when I tried it, and the only thing I had to do was git push.